# rosserial spinOnce() blocks if not connected to ROS

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using rosserial with an Arduino, I find that spinOnce() blocks if not connected to ROS, which makes sense (since how can you locally know when to go), so I am wondering if the standard call (for nodeHandle nh) inside the loop() should be:

```
if (nh.connected()) nh.spinOnce();
else {  ....deal with having disconnected from ROS and make the robot safe....then wait for reconnection....}
```

I saw on the logging page:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Overview/Logging

```
//wait until you are actually connected
while (!nh.connected() ){
    nh.spinOnce();
}
```

but from what I am seeing with the arduino, you would get the same result with

```
nh.spinOnce();
```

alone, since it blocks.  Is that correct?

Once ROS has disconnected, is there some way to put the arduino in a state where it can accept a reconnect cleanly?

Thanks again for all your help with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11239/rosserial-spinonce()-blocks-if-not-connected-to-ros/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2011-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Dan,

spinOnce should never block.  It just checks to see if new serial data has come in and fires callback messages if it has received a full message.  It is supposed to work just like spinOnce in roscpp.  All it handles is com and callbacks.

Under what situations are you seeing it block?

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1